# 6mm spacing between footnote number and text

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footer

I want to add an 6mm spacing in my footer between the 1. and the text in the bottom part of the footnote. Example: 1.(6mm space here)not to be confused with hay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[supstfm=libertinesups]{superiors}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark. }

\renewcommand*\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\noindent The three little pigs built their houses
out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources}
and bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to measure the width at begin document, when `\footnotesize` is known.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[supstfm=libertinesups]{superiors}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\newlength{\fmwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\fmwidth}{\footnotesize 00.}%
  \addtolength{\fmwidth}{6mm}%
  \deffootnote[\fmwidth]{\fmwidth}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{6mm}}%
}

\textheight=2.2cm % just to compress the picture

\begin{document}

The three little pigs built their houses
out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources} \setcounter{footnote}{9}
and bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.

\noindent{\footnotesize 10.\hspace{6mm}probably}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't plan to have more than nine footnotes, use `0.` instead of `00.`

Answer (score 4):

Add the 6mm spacing to the `<format code>` part of `\deffootnote` and adjust for this addition in `<indent>`:

```
\deffootnote[<mark indent>]{<indent>}{<par indent>}{<format code>}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[supstfm=libertinesups]{superiors}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\deffootnote{\dimexpr1.5em+6mm}{1em}{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{6mm}}

\renewcommand*\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\noindent The three little pigs built their houses
out of straw\footnote{not to be confused with hay},
sticks\footnote{or lumber according to some sources}
and bricks\footnote{probably fired clay bricks}.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```